# Pass in object prop as JSX attributes instead of object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, spread-syntax

Given the following component. I'm looking for a way to take these props, attributes and pass them in to another component in this format.

```
<AdminHeader
  logoSource='https://dummyimage.com/85x85/c718de/ffffff'
  leftStyle={{flexGrow: 2}}
  centerText={'Painel De Administração · Clientes'}
  rightStyle={{flexBasis: 'content', flexGrow: 0}}
  right={(
    <AdminNotification
      imageSource='https://dummyimage.com/65x85/a8a8a8/000000.png'
      circleScheme='red'
      count={21}
      text='Admin Master'
    />
  )}
/>
```

For instance let's say I wrap `<AdminHeader/>` like this:

```
function WrappedAdminHeader (props) {
  return (
    <AdminHeader {...props.adminHeader}/>
  )
}
```

Then I want to call `<WrappedAdminHeader />` and pass in `adminHeader` props without having to convert them all to `JSON`:

```
<WrappedAdminHeader
  adminHeader={(
    <ResolveToJSON
      logoSource='https://dummyimage.com/85x85/c718de/ffffff'
      leftStyle={{flexGrow: 2}}
      centerText={'Painel De Administração · Clientes'}
      rightStyle={{flexBasis: 'content', flexGrow: 0}}
      right={(
        <AdminNotification
          imageSource='https://dummyimage.com/65x85/a8a8a8/000000.png'
          circleScheme='red'
          count={21}
          text='Admin Master'
        />
      )}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Rather then having to convert the attributes to JSON like this:

```
<WrappedAdminHeader adminHeader={{
  logoSource: 'https://dummyimage.com/85x85/c718de/ffffff',
  leftStyle: {flexGrow: 2},
  centerText: 'Painel De Administração · Clientes',
  rightStyle: {flexBasis: 'content', flexGrow: 0},
  right:(
    <AdminNotification
      imageSource='https://dummyimage.com/65x85/a8a8a8/000000.png'
      circleScheme='red'
      count={21}
      text='Admin Master'
    />
  )}}
}>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Your second 2 examples aren't clear to me. What is `<ResolveToJSON>`?

Comment: I think I see what you're saying... This has nothing to do with JSON but you want to use a jsx node and attributes instead of an object literal to specify the props for AdminHeader. I don't think there's really any point to that. You could just pass an AdminHeader in as a prop and render it in WrappedAdminHeader from props.children.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want the attributes of `<WrappedAdminHeader>` to be passed to `<AdminHeader>` you can just use attribute spread directly on the props:

```
function WrappedAdminHeader (props) {
  return (
    <AdminHeader {...props}/>
  )
}
```

Now you can use `<WrappedAdminHeader>` as a drop-in replacement for `<AdminHeader>`:

```
<WrappedAdminHeader
  logoSource='https://dummyimage.com/85x85/c718de/ffffff'
  leftStyle={{flexGrow: 2}}
  centerText={'Painel De Administração · Clientes'}
  rightStyle={{flexBasis: 'content', flexGrow: 0}}
  right={(
    <AdminNotification
      imageSource='https://dummyimage.com/65x85/a8a8a8/000000.png'
      circleScheme='red'
      count={21}
      text='Admin Master'
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was aware of this already, this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
const A = ({ message }) => <span>{message}</span>;
const B = ({ propsForA }) => <A {...propsForA} />;

const a = <A message="Hi!" />;    

const App = () => (
  <div>{<B propsForA={a.props} />}</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("entry")
);
```

Where you take the props from `a` which is an "instance" of `A`.